# How to Run a OpenCL program from Command Line using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, opencl

I'm creating a Build button in my application which can take two source code files .cpp and .cl

It should make use of Command line to set the header files, libraries and OpenCL.lib which i usually set manually through VS Configuration Settings.

Hope there is some way to pass these Additional Libraries and Header files and compile the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're doing, and it really depends on how you want your application to work.

The VS configuration settings live in a .vcxproj file. Does this live with the input .cpp/.ci files? If so, you would be better off compiling the source files by calling "msbuild.exe" on the project file. Instead of providing the .cpp/.ci files as input, it would be the .vcxproj file.

If there isn't any associated .vcxproj with the .cpp/.ci files, but it instead lives with your application, then you'll have to parse the .vcxproj directly and search for the XML tags that contain this information (eg: ). Obviously, this will be a little more work. Alternatively, this could live in a completely separate text file that lists the library paths, header paths, etc. that you want to build the source files with.

Again, without fully understanding what you're trying to do, it's difficult to give a clear answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Gave me a path to walk on :) I might get back if i feel lost.